How to provide my own custom pagination footer and to have all pagination functionalities?
I want Tabulator to perform all the pagination for me locally but want to provide my own custom pagination controls.
I am using:

"react-tabulator": "^0.9.1"

is there a way to include a rows indicator within the Tabulator pagination that displays something like:
1-25 of 80 rows
The above indicates that we are displaying rows 1 to 25 out of a total of 80 rows.
I have tried to call tablechanged and pagechanged function to trigger the function, but it's not working. Anyone having better solution with that above version.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
